# Incorrect integer value: 'caa506cd-a6c6-4907-9a70-81be26324cf3' for column 'notifiable_id'

Tags: laravel

I'm following the notifications tutorial at Laravel docs but I'm getting the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 
'caa506cd-a6c6-4907-9a70-81be26324cf3' 
for column 'notifiable_id' at row 1 

(SQL: insert into `notifications` (
    `id`, 
    `type`, 
    `data`, 
    `read_at`, 
    `notifiable_id`, 
    `notifiable_type`, 
    `updated_at`, 
    `created_at`
) values (
    18983710-8eaf-4784-8015-63c078e93866, 
    App\Notifications\UserSelectedToInterview, 
    {"company_name":"McDonalds","job_title":null}, 
    , 
    caa506cd-a6c6-4907-9a70-81be26324cf3, 
    App\User, 
    2018-09-23 16:20:24, 2018-09-23 16:20:24)
)
```

when I'm calling

```
// Create the notification for the users
Notification::send(User::whereIn('id', $candidates->pluck('user_id'))
    ->select('id')
    ->get(),

new UserSelectedToInterview($loggedCompany->name, $job->title));
```

With my notifications migration being:

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('type');
    $table->morphs('notifiable');
    $table->text('data');
    $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I'm assuming that `$table->morphs('notifiable');` is expecting an `int` but my `User` model is using as a primary key a `uuid`.

At my `User` model I have that specified with `protected $keyType = 'string';`

Any idea on where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 hours later *banging my head against the wall*

Basically the problem if anyone is wondering is the `morph()` method.

The method behind it is:

```
/**
 * Add the proper columns for a polymorphic table.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string|null  $indexName
 * @return void
 */
public function morphs($name, $indexName = null)
{
    $this->unsignedInteger("{$name}_id");

    $this->string("{$name}_type");

    $this->index(["{$name}_id", "{$name}_type"], $indexName);
}
```

Instead of using `morph()` you can add the fields by yourself:

```
$table->string('notifiable_type');
$table->uuid('notifiable_id');
// Don't forget to add the indexes
$table->index(['notifiable_type', 'notifiable_id']);
```

Props to this answer [How to make laravel Blueprints morphs method to add column after a specified column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493616/how-to-make-laravel-blueprints-morphs-method-to-add-column-after-a-specified-col)

Answer (score 4):

updated answer for `laravel 6.x`

instead of using @charlie's answer you can simply use `uuidMorphs`

in your `notifications_table_migration`

Change this:

```
$table->morphs('notifiable');
```

To:

```
$table->uuidMorphs('notifiable');
```

`uuidMorphs` function:

```
/**
     * Add the proper columns for a polymorphic table using UUIDs.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string|null  $indexName
     * @return void
     */
    public function uuidMorphs($name, $indexName = null)
    {
        $this->string("{$name}_type");

        $this->uuid("{$name}_id");

        $this->index(["{$name}_type", "{$name}_id"], $indexName);
    }
```

Thanks.